# Is there any advantage to putting headers in an "include" subdir of the project?

Tags: c++, header-files, project-structure

I've noticed that the source of the popular C++ library [Cinder](https://libcinder.org/) has separate `src` and `include` folders, containing `*.cpp` and `*.h` files correspondingly. Is there an advantage to doing it this way rather than simply putting every .cpp in the same dir as its matching .h?

Comment: Personally I do not see advantages, and I dislike doing it. I think that in C++ a cpp file comes with its header and must not be separated from it.

Answer (score 8):

Its often easier to structure your code this way, especially if you are going to export it as an API with pre-compiled libraries. The (public) headers then become your API, it makes sense to keep them in a separate place from the source as this is the part of the code that will have to be distributed with the library.

Comment: I tend to put public API headers for a library in a 'include' dir and other headers that are internal to the library in a 'src' dir alongside the .cc files. This makes it easy to package the binaries + include dir for users and keeping implementation-detail headers out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

Usable options are

- `module/*.{cpp,h}` - best for spacial locality of related files, worst when need to apply strict API focus (backward compatibility, release vs patch, etc.)
- `module/{include/*.h, src/*.{cpp,h}}` - good for API focus, good for spacial locality, **my preferred choice**
- `include/module/*.h,src/module/*.{cpp,h}` - best for API focus, not very good for spacial locality

Answer (score 0):

There is no real pros an cons, well not in general. When designing API (compared to applications), you will have to provide a set of includes with your library and this particular rôle of header files make developper choose to solution of separating them from sources in their filesystem.

I don't think an organisation is better than an other but I can give you two adviced to help you decide what is best for your projects :

- Try to simplify you file hierarchy as much as possible. When it comes to project configuration, install scripts and version control, less embedded folders is less headaches.
- The most important is not where header files are located but *how they are included*:

  - <> or ""
  - From internal source files or from external code which uses your headers ?
  - With a path to them or directly the file name ?

Seing how you want your headers to be written when calling `#include` helps you decide where it's more comfortable for you to put them.

As far as I'm concerned I don't really like headers/source separations. Some headers are not meant to be exposed by my APIs so either I have all my sources in one folder or I prefer a public/private separation.